# GPIO readout from Geiger Müller board is low when it clicks

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3

I am using a RPI 3b and [this](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/32884861168.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2deu&spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.5faf6aa9OuQXsc) board. I setup everything according to [this](https://www.balena.io/blog/build-a-simple-radiation-monitor-using-a-raspberry-pi-influxdb-and-grafana/) guide. It's also my first RPI project so maybe I am missing something.

The code I am running:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)

print(GPIO.input(4))
counter = 0

while 1:
    if (GPIO.input(4) == 1):
        print("Click - {}".format(counter))
        counter = counter + 1
```

Pretty straight forward, right? If I run it, it just loops and increments the counter until I stop it. If I check if

```
GPIO.input(4) == 0
```

it suddenly works and only prints/increments the counter whenever the geiger counter beeps. Could anyone explain this to me please?

Thanks!

Comment: explain what? ... it is not clear what you do not understand

Comment: Sounds like normal behaviour for that board. Output is normally high, low for a click.

Comment: @jsotola - I don't understand why the output is low - I thought I should check for high output.

Comment: @CoderMike - tbh. it took me a while until I tried looking for low output and was surprised it worked. So do you think it's fine if I leave it like that? I tried other gpios but it was the same.

Comment: what's there to understand? ... it's designed that way ... refer to the device datasheet ... do not make assumptions about output levels ... instead print the  value of GPIO.input(4) ... that way you know what the level is when not detecting a signal and adjust your code accordingly